# Simple django DetailView doesn't work, how to pass to pass 2 arguments to DetailView

Tags: django

I want to create detail view for my Playlist model. I followed steps from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)  and i keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError at /root
Generic detail view PlaylistDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.
```

here is my code:

model:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    miniature = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/playlist', default="defaults/default.png", validators=[validate_miniature_file_extension])
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(Track)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

url:

```
path('<slug:author>', PlaylistDetail.as_view(), name='playlist'),
```

view:

```
class PlaylistDetail(DetailView):
    model = Playlist
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

I suppose its caused because of that there are more than one playlist created by the same user, and it will must get User && title. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the urls, you use `<slug:author>`

```
path('<slug:author>', PlaylistDetail.as_view(), name='playlist'),
```

And by default it looks for `slug`.

Try updating the view with this:

```
class PlaylistDetail(DetailView):
    model = Playlist
    slug_url_kwarg = 'author' # <----
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # . . .
```

Comment: Thank you. But how to it for multiple slugs? For url that contain <slug:user> and <slug:title> (like this: path('<slug:author>/<slug:title>', PlaylistDetail.as_view(), name='playlist')

Comment: One possibility is to override the `get_object` method, then you have full control over how the object is found. And will be able to access the variables you mention with `self.kwargs['author']` and `self.kwargs['title']`

Comment: I can use it in get_object method by self.kwargs['author']?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it like that anywhere.